# Jackson exception on writeValueAsString method

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to integrate Jackson on my java code to convert object to Json and back. My project is a web application developed in for Tomcat7 and Java7. I just downloaded the last version (2.6.0) jars of Jackson and was trying to do convert an object to json.

```
String outJson ="";
myobject p = new myobject ();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); // can reuse, share globally
try {
      outJson = mapper.writeValueAsString(p);
} catch (Exception e) {
    out.println(e.toString());
}
```

When I run this, I get an exception like this:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException)
```

I have done the oposite way, converting from json to the object and the result was ok.

After some research I found some references to posible dependency problem, but I can not find what I am missing. I have included the following jars, obtained from Maven repository:

```
jackson-annotations-2.6.0.jar
jackson-core-2.6.0.jar
jackson-databind-2.6.0.jar
jackson-dataformat-smile-2.6.0.jar
jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.6.0.jar
jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.6.0.jar
```

Any ideas of what could be the problem?

Comment: Please provide full stack trace

Comment: Mind sharing the code for the myobject class?

Comment: Just found it. It was an easy one but looking at the wrong side. Object was actually empty.

Comment: at what line of the code is the null pointer thrown? please share all the code if possible. maybe some property is null? Try this in your myobject declaration: @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments the problem was that I was not initializing correctly the object. As there was no data, I got the NullPointerException.